# Multivariate Gaussian distribution formula implementation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave, cluster-analysis, gaussian

I have a certain problem while implementing multivariate Gaussian distribution for anomaly detection.

I have referred the formula from Andrew Ng notes

```
http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/15_Anomaly_Detection.html
```

below is the problem I face

Suppose I have a data set with 2 features and m number of training set i.e n=2 and wants to determine my multivariate Gaussian probability p(x;mu;sigma) which should be a [m*1] matrix because it produces estimated Gaussian value by feature correlation.

The problem I face is I am unable to use the formula to produce the matrix [m*1].

I am using Octave as IDE to develop the algorithm.

Below is a snapshot showcasing my problem

[image]

Considering the multiplication of the Red boundary equation because the LHS of the red boundary is just a real number

[image]

PLEASE HELP ME UNDERSTAND WHERE AM I GOING WRONG

Thanks

Comment: The answer is simple: `m=1`. Mathematically, you compute one instance at a time. I don't know if this is amenable to Matlab hacks of "vectorization".

Comment: what does the abs(sigma)^0.5 mean? Why is it a real number, isnt it a matrix

Comment: It is not abs() but det()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got the dimensions wrong.

Let's assume you have a 2-dimensional (`n=2`) data of `m` instances. We can store this data as a `n-by-m` matrix in MATLAB (columns are data instances, rows represent features/dimensions). In this case we have:

- `X` the data matrix of size `nxm`, each instance `x = X(:,i)` is a vector of size `nx1` (column vector in our convention).
- `mu` is the mean vector (`mu = mean(X,2)`). This is also a column vector of same size as an instance `nx1`.
- `sigma` is the covariance matrix (`sigma = cov(X.')`). It has size `nxn` (it describes how each dimensions co-vary with each other dimension).

So the part that you highlighted in red involves expressions of the following sizes:

```
 = ([nx1] - [nx1])' * [nxn] * ([nx1] - [nx1])
 = [1xn] * [nxn] * [nx1]
 = 1x1
```

Comment: So you mean the above dimension multiplication solves for one instance, similarly all the instances can be found independently and hence we get our [
m x 1] matrix considering all instances.

Comment: yes, you compute `p(x)` for each instance `x = X(:,i)` (`for i=1:m`) one at-a-time. If you have access to the Statistics Toolbox in MATLAB, take a look at [`edit mvnpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html) for a vectorized implementation