# How to take advantage of vectorization when computing the pdf for a multivariate gaussian?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, gaussian

I've been spending a few hours googling about this problem and it seems I can't find any information.

I tried coding a multivariate gaussian pdf as:

```
def multivariate_normal(X, M, S):

    # X has shape (D, N) where D is the number of dimensions and N the number of observations
    # M is the mean vector with shape (D, 1)
    # S is the covariance matrix with shape (D, D)

    D = S.shape[0]
    S_inv = np.linalg.inv(S)
    logdet = np.log(np.linalg.det(S))
    log2pi = np.log(2*np.pi)
    devs = X - M

    a = np.array([- D/2 * log2pi - (1/2) * logdet - dev.T @ S_inv @ dev for dev in devs.T])

return np.exp(a)
```

I've only been successful in computing the pdf through a for loop, iterating N times. If I don't, I end up with an (N, N) matrix which is unhelpful. I've found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611816/multivariate-gaussian-distribution-formula-implementation), but the post is quite outdated and in matlab.

Is there anyway to take advantage of numpy's vectorisation?

This is my first post on stackoverflow, let me know if anything is off!d

Comment: What about just using the in-built functions (scipy): https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem in a similar manner and here's how I solved it:

Variables:

- X = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]] - m x n
- MU = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]] - k x n
- SIGMA = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]]] - k x n x n
- k = int

Where X is my feature vector, MU is my means, SIGMA is my covariance matrix.

To vectorize, I rewrote the dot product per the definition of the dot-product:

```
sigma_det = np.linalg.det(sigma)
sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
const = 1/((2*np.pi)**(n/2)*sigma_det**(1/2))
p = const*np.exp((-1/2)*np.sum((X-mu).dot(sigma_inv)*(X-mu),axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this problem for the last few days and finally have come to a solution.

To do so I have added an extra dimension to the x vector, and then used the `np.einsum()` function for computing the Mahalanobis distance.

### Example

For the following example we will use a (100 x 2) input array. That is, 100 samples of two random variables. That gives us a (1 x 2) mean vector and a (2 x 2) covariance matrix.

Generating some data:

```
# instantiate a random number generator
rng = np.random.default_rng(100)

# define mu and sigma for the dummy sample
mu = np.array([0.5, 0.25])
covmat = np.array([[1, 0.5],
                   [0.5, 1]])

# generate multivariate normal random sample
x = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, covmat, size=100)
```

And defining the pdf function:

```
def pdf(x, mu, covmat):
        """
          Generates the probability of a given x vector based on the
          probability distribution function N(mu, covmat)

          Returns: the probability
        """
        x = x[:, np.newaxis] # add a new first dimension to x
        k = mu.shape[0]  # number of dimensions
        diff = x - mu  # deviation of x from the mean
        inv_covmat = np.linalg.inv(covmat)

        term1 = (2*np.pi)**-(k/2)*np.linalg.det(inv_covmat)
        term2 = np.exp(-np.einsum('ijk, kl, ijl->ij', diff, inv_covmat, diff) / 2)
        return term1 * term2
```

Which returns a (n, 1) array, where n is the number of samples, in this case (100,1).

### Explanation

The easiest way to think about solving the problem is just writing down the dimensions, and trying to do the linear algebra.

We need to do some kind of manipulation of three tensors with the following shapes, to get the resulting tensor:

`A, B, C -> D`

(100 x 1 x 2), (2, 2), (100 x 1 x 2) -> (100 x 1)

Let the first tensor, A, have the indices, `ijk`:

Then we want to do some operation of A and B to get the shape (100 x 1 x 2).

Hence,

`ijk, kl - > ijl`

(100 x 1 x 2), (2 x 2) -> (100 x 1 x 2)

This leaves us with AB, C

(100 x 1 x 2), (100 x 1 x 2)

We want D to have the shape (100 x 1)

Hence:

`ijl, ijl->ij`

(100 x 1 x 2), (100 x 1 x 2) -> (100 x 1)

Putting the two operations together, we get:

`ijk, kl, ijl->ij`

Comment: cool explanation of einsum, it is a difficult one :D

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you could offer a conclusive example using the randomly generated points and the pdf (minimal example)